# Undefined object after export - Node.js

Tags: node.js, object, express, asynchronous, export

I hope you can help me to resolve my problem.

So I want to export an object from the file 'hostconf.js' and import it into my 'routes.js' file.
But in this last file, my object is undefined.
I think the problem is that the routes file is read before the hostconf file.

Is there a way to resolve this ?

My code from hostconf file :

```
getSystemInfo(function (manufacturer, model, serial){
    hostSystem = [os.hostname(), manufacturer + ' ' + model, serial];
    console.log('Hostconf File : ' + hostSystem);
    module.exports = {hostSystem: hostSystem};
});
```

My code from routes file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var hostSystem = require('./hostconf').hostSystem;
console.log('Routes file : ' + hostSystem);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('kbagent-interface', { hostSystem: hostSystem});
});
```

My output :

```
Routes file : undefined
kbagent:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
Hostconf File : PC, Acer Aspire, XTS6595DFF
```

Thank you very much  :)

Comment: Your getSystemInfo method should be getting exported. You are trying to export within your method.. never seen that done before. Try putting your module.exports outside of the getSystemInfo method and do module.exports = { getSystemInfo: getSystemInfo } and then invoke that in your router so do var systemInfo = getSystemInfo(foo, bar, foo) and then you can do systemInfo.hostSystem in your res.render - That should work

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a  beginner in nodejs and I do not know the language... sorry for these huge mistakes.